# Regular expressions match floating point number but not integer

Tags: regex, floating-point, integer

I have a problem to define a regexp that matches floating point numbers but do NOT identify integers.

I have the following regular expression, which matches floating numbers.

```
(\+|-)?([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)([eE](\+|-)?[0-9]+)?
```

How can I modify the expression above so that it doesn't match integers?

Here is a example of what should be matched:

```
3.3
.3
5E6
.2e-14
7E+3
4.
5.E2
1e2
```

Comment: Please confirm: only `#.`, `#.#`, `.#`, `#.e#`, `#.#e#` and `.#e#` should be matched?

Comment: See http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html

Comment: @user1285737: Should a string like '1e2' be matched?

Comment: yes, 1e2 should be matched...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your regex flavor supports lookaheads, require one of the floating-point characters before the end of the number:

```
((\+|-)?(?=\d*[.eE])([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)([eE](\+|-)?[0-9]+)?
```

[Additional reading.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Here is also a slightly optimized version:

```
[+-]?(?=\d*[.eE])(?=\.?\d)\d*\.?\d*(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?
```

We start with an optional `+` or `-`. Then we require one of the characters `.`, `e` or `E` after an arbitrary amount of digits. Then we also require at least one digit, either before or after the string. The we just match digits, an optional `.` and more digits. Then (completely optional) an `e` or an `E` and optional `+` or `-` and then one or more digits.

Comment: A cleaner regex version with no wild `(` at the start - [`[+-]?(?=\d*[.eE])([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/7xruwB/1)

Answer (score 0):

This one should suit your needs:

```
[+-]?([0-9]+\.([0-9]+)?|\.[0-9]+)([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?
```

Comment: @MarkDickinson `1e2` won't match. `1.e2` and `.1e2` will though.

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked.  `1e2` is usually a valid representation of a float, so I'd expect that the OP would want that to be matched.  But it's not clear from the question.  Guess I should have posted the above comment on the question rather than on your answer.  Sorry. :-)