# Regex for Matching a Floating Point Number which is not an Integer

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regular expression which I use to find numbers in strings

```
-?\d*\.?\d+([eE][-+]?\d+)?
```

and wish to modify it such that it *only* matches floating point numbers and not integers.  The criteria for this (as best I can discern) is that the match must feature at least one of: `.`, `e`, `E`.  However, I can not think of a nice way of incorporating this requirement into the regex without duplicating most of the body.

**Duplicate**

After a bit of searching I came across [Regular expressions match floating point number but not integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252101/regular-expressions-floating-point-number) which although not clearly titled is an exact duplicate of this problem (incl. soln).

Comment: Is "1E1" an integer or a floating point number?

Comment: Good question: I would go for a floating point number; Python's int(...) method rejects it and C, IIRC, will classify it as a float.

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: If you can show some sample text or input it would be a lot better ?

Comment: Does Python regex support negative lookaheads? If so, try adding `(?!\d+\b)` right after the first minus test. I *think* it will not stop on a possible '+' or '-'.

Comment: Do you want to avoid matching a minus sign when it's part of an arithmetic expression? That is, should the second number matched in `"1.0-3.5"` be negative? Or do you not need to worry about that (because you're only matching single "terms" at a time, not searching in a larger document that may have multiple results)?

Comment: @Blckknght With or without the minus sign is fine for me.

Comment: I've retitled the linked-duplicate so it's a bit more descriptive now

Comment: Why not just get all the numbers and then go `int('1.1')`. If you get an error (which you should catch), then the number string is definitely not an integer? Be careful not to use `float` as that will be happy to convert integers to floats (e.g. `float('1')` returns `1.0`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following regex does this, although it's a bit cryptic:

```
-?(?:\d+())?(?:\.\d*())?(?:e-?\d+())?(?:\2|\1\3)
```

**Explanation:**

There are three parts to a number (integer part, fractional part and exponential part). If a fractional part is present, it's a `float`, but if it isn't present, the number can still be a float when an exponential part follows.

This means that we first have to make all three parts optional in the regex. But then we need to build rules that specify exactly which parts need to be there to make a valid float.

Fortunately, there's a trick that allows us to do that. An empty capturing group (`()`) always matches (the empty string). A backreference to that group (`\1`) only succeeds if the group has participated in the match. By inserting a `()` in each of the optional groups, we can later test whether the required parts have participated in the match.

For example, in Python:

```
regex = re.compile(r"""
    -?    # Optional minus sign
   (?:    # Start of the first non-capturing group:
    \d+   #  Match a number (integer part)
    ()    #  Match the empty string, capture in group 1
   )?     # Make the first non-capturing group optional
   (?:    # Start of the second non-capturing group:
    \.\d* #  Match a dot and an optional fractional part
    ()    #  Match the empty string, capture in group 2
   )?     # Make the second non-capturing group optional
   (?:    # Start of the third non-capturing group:
    e     #  Match an e or E
    -?    #  Match an optional minus sign
    \d+   #  Match a mandatory exponent
    ()    #  Match the empty string, capture in group 3
   )?     # Make the third non-capturing group optional
  (?:     # Now make sure that at least the following groups participated:
   \2     #  Either group 2 (containing the empty string)
  |       # or
   \1\3   #  Groups 1 and 3 (because "1" or "e1" alone aren't valid matches)
  )""", re.I|re.X)
```

Test suite:

```
>>> [match.group(0) for match in
...        regex.finditer("1 1.1 .1 1. 1e1 1.04E-1 -.1 -1. e1 .1e1")]
['1.1', '.1', '1.', '1e1', '1.04E-1', '-.1', '-1.', '.1e1']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd just go for

```
(-?\d*\.\d+([eE][-+]?\d+)?) | (-?\d+[eE][-+]?\d+)
```

The first part is identical to your original expression, but requires the period. The second catches the cases without the period, requiring the `[eE][-+]?\d+` part.

Comment: This doesn't match `'4.'`.

Comment: Neither does the original regex. I'm assuming he does not want to match '4.' as a floating point number, which is just as reasonable as wanting to match it.

Comment: I'm guessing that's a mistake, since `'4.'` is a valid float literal in both Python and C (and probably lots of other languages that I'm not as familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution, using a lookahead to allow `'1e1'`, but not other values without decimal points:

```
>>> pattern = r'[+-]?(?:\d+\.\d*|\.\d+|\d+(?=[eE]))(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?'
>>> re.match(pattern, '4.')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000000000347BD30>
>>> re.match(pattern, '4.4')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000000000347BCC8>
>>> re.match(pattern, '.4')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000000000347BD30>
>>> re.match(pattern, '4e4')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000000000347BCC8>
```